# Powershell: How do I get the name from Azure Active Directory user (Get-AzADUser)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Very simple question. I want to get the name of user john@doe.com from Azure's Active Directory. For that purpose I used

```
$user = Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName "john@doe.com"
```

What am I now supposed to do with `$user`? According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azaduser?view=azps-4.7.0#outputs) Get-AzADUser returns a Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADUser object. However, Microsoft fails to link to a documentation of PSADUser and I cannot find one. Trying to view the content by just typing

```
$user
```

yields

```
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADUser
```

So how can I now see what is inside this object? Or is there a completely different approach I should consider?

Comment: Does `$user | fl` show anything?

Comment: No, it also returns ```Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADUser```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get $user details to follow bellow steps

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

next run bellow cmd and copy user principal name for the particular user

```
Get-AzADUser
```

use the above UserPrincipalName for bellow code

```
 $user = Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName "Sruthi_xxx.live#EXT#@exchangetestdomain.onmicrosoft.com"
```

[image]